# Environment variables are wrongly taken in a Next.js static application in an Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, next.js, environment-variables

We have a Next.js application that is getting the API Url and use for its own purposes.

This Url is different for every environment the application runs, for this reason, the application reads this value from an environment variable. If we build and export (to get the static code for deployment) the application locally, the code works just fine.

The API Url is read inside a component in the Next.js application as follows:

```
const apiUrl: string = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL as string;
```

We are now deployng the code using an Azure pipeline that is creating the `.env` file using a Powershell task. This is the task in the YML file:

```
...
- task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          new-item -itemtype file -path $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -name ".env" -force -value '$(NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)'
...
```

the `.env` file created seems fine as we are printing this out in the Azure logs.

The static Next.js application code should use the variable `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` from this `.env` file at build time (of course, the Next.js build happen in the Azure pipeline after creating the `.env`).

**Here comes the problem**: when the code is deployed in the Azure pipeline, the `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` is read with the declaration as well, this means that the previous string will read this:

```
apiUrl = "NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://apiurldomain/api"
```

rather than just:

```
apiUrl = "https://apiurldomain/api"
```

Anyone had the same issue? Anyone knows why?

Any solution for that?

Comment: Hi Ferie; can you check two things? Firstly, what is the value of the pipeline variable "NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL" before the .env file is created? Secondly, exactly what is the content of the .env file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing the valid **API URL** in a **NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL** pipeline variable.

Avoid using the **single quotes** in your pipeline while set the file content value of your PowerShell script. I have noticed this in my pipeline script. If we use Single quotes in a script it takes that as string and it saves in a file.

change the

```js
 value '$(NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)'
```

into

```js
-value $NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
```

I have slightly modified your pipeline.

```js
...
- task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
        #avoid using single quotes while you set the values in a file  
          new-item -itemtype file -path $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -name ".env" -force -value $NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
...
```

I have done this workaround in my local environment.
[image]